# Comments in Perl5 crash the program?

Tags: perl, comments

I'm teaching myself Perl with the help of some internet tutorials, and for the most part it's going really well and everything runs smoothly. However, I cannot do ANY comments, whatsoever, or the program won't run properly. For example, the following code:

```
#eee
print "Estimation of Pi";
```

will run, but not print anything, while just this

```
print "Estimation of Pi";
```

runs and prints what it's meant to.

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand this at all.

Also, on a side note, what is #!/usr/bin/perl needed for? My programs seem to be running fine without it (and being a comment, the programs don't work WITH it)

Comment: How are you running your Perl scripts? What environment on you on?

Comment: What value do you get for the character that you're typing as '`#`'?  For example, if you do '`od -c file.pl`', do you see a '`#`'?  Ideally, if you do a character-by-character hex dump, is the code for '`#`' 0x23?  I'm not sure what else it could be, but it is weird behaviour you're seeing.   The `#!/usr/bin/perl` (shebang) notation means that if you type `file.pl` (instead of `perl file.pl`), the correct program (`/usr/bin/perl`) will be executed.

Comment: @EricStrom, it returns Perl 5.14.2.

Comment: @Sarnold, as I said below, W7 64bit, ActivePerl 64bit, through the command line simply using 'test.pl' to execute.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, `od -c file.pl` is not recognised, I'm on Windows. What's weird is that my programs run without `#!/usr/bin/perl` when I type `file.pl`, but not with `#!/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: @user1092865 => since you are on windows, the #! line is ignored.  What program are you using to edit your perl file?  Is it a programmers text editor, or a word processor?

Comment: "crashing" is a lot different than "not print anything".

Comment: With a very short version of your script that exhibits the problem (i.e., doesn't print anything), what is the output of `perl -pe "s/./sprintf(' %02x', ord($&))/eg" tmp.pl` ?  This dumps the contents of your script in hexadecimal, so we can see exactly what characters are in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your file doesn't contain what you think it does. Perhaps you have a CR instead of a LF or CRLF.

```
>perl -e"binmode STDOUT; print qq{#eee\rprint qq{foo\\n}}" | perl

>perl -e"binmode STDOUT; print qq{#eee\nprint qq{foo\\n}}" | perl
foo

>perl -e"binmode STDOUT; print qq{#eee\r\nprint qq{foo\\n}}" | perl
foo
```

Examine your file with a hex editor, or at worse with the following command:

```
perl -0777nE"BEGIN { binmode STDIN } say join ' ', unpack '(A2)*', unpack 'H*', $_" < file
```

`#!` is a unix concept. Windows doesn't use it, but Perl will look for command line option on that line. For example, the following will warn:

```
#!perl -w
print undef;
```

Comment: To elaborate in case anyone else has a similar problem, I was using Notepad++ to edit my .pl files. I used View -> Show Symbols -> Show End Of Line, which showed me just CR's at the end. Then I used Edit -> EOL Format -> Windows to change it.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds pretty weird. How are you executing that program? If you're running that program on a system that expects windows-style newlines but creating it with a text editor that generates unix-style newlines that would cause your problem. Try making sure that you text editor is configured to use windows-style newlines if you are on windows.

The `#!/usr/bin/perl` is not a comment. That's called a shebang line, and on unix systems, if you execute a text file (that is, you `chmod +x filename.pl` and then execute it with `./filename.pl` rather than `perl filename.pl`), the system looks for that on the very first line and if it finds it, passes the whole file to the utility located at that file, in this case `/usr/bin/perl`. It is useful only on unix systems and only when you want to make the script executable.

As another tip - perl uses an output buffer for anything passed to `print`. That means that if you `print` something that doesn't end in a newline (`\n`), it's held in a buffer until either you flush the buffer (not usually something necessary in perl), print something containing a newline, or exit the program. You can override this functionality by adding `$| = 1;` to your program, but it's best to just end your messages with newlines, otherwise your screen just gets cluttered up.

Comment: Sorry I should have put this info in the OP. I'm using Windows 64bit, with ActivePerl 64bit. I'm going through the command line, navigating to the directory where my scripts are stored and running them simply with 'test.pl'. I'll add more info in a sec.

Comment: It's the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Crunchbang is a linux distro.

Comment: Huh. Crunchbang uses `#!` as their logo, I always assumed they were named after it too.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're executing the script as a shell script, not a Perl script, and that you happen to have a `print` command in your `$PATH`.  This assumes you're in a Unix-like environment.  (Which, as it turns out, you're not; you're on Windows.  But this answer might be useful to others.)

What happens if you change `print` to `echo`?  Since `echo` isn't a valid Perl command, if it still works my guess is probably right.

The very first line of your script should be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

This "shebang" tells the system how to execute the script when you run it by name.  Or you can run it with `perl` explicitly:

```
perl ./script_name
```